# why "Good & Bad Maps" changed to community wiki

Tags: discussion

The first day the examples of [good](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3083/examples-of-beautiful-maps) and [bad maps](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3087/examples-of-badly-designed-maps) questions went up someone flagged them as "should be community wiki". I personally resisted for a few days because in the wake of the recent [removal of CW check box](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/392/should-the-community-wiki-police-be-shut-down/7183#7183) on new questions I have some confusion as to what should or shouldn't be community wiki, and waited to see what the other moderators would do.

Today in ["Should poll questions be Community Wiki?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14308/should-poll-questions-be-community-wiki/14318#14318) I found a sentiment which crystalized things for me and I acted.

> In principle, there's no reason why
>   they should be [community wiki]. Either the question is
>   off-topic and should be removed, or
>   it's on-topic and its wiki state
>   should be at the discretion of its
>   author.
>
> In practice, there's a very good
>   reason why they should be: polls work
>   very, very poorly when answers cannot
>   be voted on without giving or taking
>   rep from the voters and votees.
>   Furthermore, when posting a popular
>   answer stands to garner rep for its
>   author, there's more temptation to
>   post a duplicate rather than up-voting
>   an existing answer. And making a
>   question CW is the only way to force
>   all answers to be CW as well.
>
> So long as the system continues to
>   work this way, poll questions should
>   always be CW for practical reasons.
>   Admins should force this upon them if
>   the original author neglects to do
>   so...

Belatedly I realised with this act I effectively pushed *Poll questions should be Community Wiki* as a general GIS.se policy without discussion, and I only momentarily hold a Moderator's torch. So, please do tell us what your thoughts are about this. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't particularly mind either way as long as people still post good answers. A question being CW has never deterred me from posting an answer, and so I hope the same can be said for everyone on this site.

I do like CW for my question as it alleviates me the duty of choosing an accepted answer, but besides that I see no benefit. I think the answers to both questions are useful to the community (and I hope people continually upload examples for a long time!)

Answer (score 1):

I created a [poll tag](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/poll) so people can filter on that if they want.

Also, while I applied the tag to [Modern day John Snow](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3188/can-you-point-me-to-an-example-of-a-modern-day-john-snow) I did not convert to CW. My reasoning being that while our site is in beta and not yet 'healthy' across [the board](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/1425/geographic-information-systems) we shouldn't limit reputation growth too quickly. So, my stance is to wait a bit and let the question develop first, and mark CW later. This is a personal opinion, everybody else should of course act as they see fit, that's what makes this system work.